# Fetch the client system name using java

Tags: java, sql

I put my server URL in my system to open web application.I need to save a system name in the database

```
String hist_query="insert into CaTbHTBL(ItemRequestno,Originator," +
        "ReqStatusFrom,ReqStatusTo,dtCreated,ItemNatureType,SysName) values" +
        "("+ur+",'"+user_name+"','--','"+check+"',getDate(),'"+SerMatVal+"','"+InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()+"')";
```

this is my query my issue is i am fetch the server name only i need to fetch my name.

Comment: Please do not concatenate user input into SQL Strings. Use a `PreparedStatement`

Comment: String hostname = "";

try
{
    InetAddress addr;
    addr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    hostname = addr.getHostName();
    System.out.println("hostname=======>>>>>>>>"+hostname);
}
catch (UnknownHostException ex)
{
    System.out.println("Hostname can not be resolved");
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a answer for my question.

```
                String hostName = request.getRemoteHost();
                   try {
                           if (hostName.equals(request.getRemoteAddr())) {
                                   InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(request.getRemoteAddr());
                                   hostName = addr.getHostName();
                           }

                           if (InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress().equals(request.getRemoteAddr())) {
                                   hostName = "Local Host";
                           }

                   }
                   catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using,

System.getProperty("user.name");

Check if you're getting the expected result.

Comment: Try, System.getProperty("COMPUTERNAME");

Comment: I am getting 'null' value for this System.getProperty("COMPUTERNAME");

Comment: System.out.println(System.getenv("USERNAME"));

Comment: now server name is coming but i need my system name kindly help me for this issue

Comment: Can you please explain what you expect. With an example because I am unable to understand what you are expecting exactly.

Comment: I am using web application and it is in server for example: abc application in server using the  server ip address i am taking and running the application in my system in this i need to take my system name. The above codes are fletching the server name not my system name. I think now you able to  understand what i am asking.